# Return promise value to generator functions in javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, generator, es6-promise

As per suggestions from @user120242 message has been updated:

Have inherited alot of js legacy code, containing only jquery ajax calls, in other words - no modern approach.

Would like to modify in a bit modern and efficient way all the ajax calls wrapped in Promises with help of Generator Function.

This is what have tried so far. What am I missing?

*PS: I do know $.get returns promise - it's only an example and other method would be used, fetch etc...*

```
    var p = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    $.get('./file.txt',
      function (content) {
        function* genFn(content){
          resolve(yield content);
        };
      });
  }).then(function(data){
      let res = data.next();
      console.log(res);
  });
```

Comment: It is really not clear what you want to do.  You just have a generator function named genFn declared in the middle of your $.get callback.  `function* genFn(content){yield content}; resolve(genFn());`?  or `function *genFn(content){resolve(yield content);} g=genFn(content);console.log(g.next(),g.next());`?  What is your understanding of generators and what problem are you actually solving?

Comment: I have a large app and there are alot of ajax calls - I can see a notification of detrimental effect on my app in console - therefore would like to refactor code to make if more efficient

Comment: you say there is a "notification of detrimental effect", what is that notification?  if you are talking about the XHR synchronous message, that is due to using synchronous calls (sync:true), which is considered an anti-pattern and automatically warned about in the console.  both fetch and $.get are asynchronous (by default), return promises, and should not cause that message.

Comment: yes-this is due to sych ajax calls, have inherited alot of legacy code and need to do improve it even if some parts are beign perceived is an anti-pattern

Comment: ah, I see.  why didn't you just say so? :p (recommend adding that concern to your question to clarify)  so for that, you don't really need to use generators.  async await already exists.  if you wish to understand how they work  you can look at https://davidwalsh.name/async-generators, https://hackernoon.com/async-await-generators-promises-51f1a6ceede2  if you end up finding that you need some kind of fancier logic for "yielding" execution flow to return an iterator of promises in ways that async await can't accomplish, is when you'd go to generators.  which should rarely happen if at all